# How can I restore a MySQL database from CakePHP model cache?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

in app\tmp\cache\models there is a file called:

```
myapp_cake_model_default_mydb_users
```

The contents are:

```
1446583948
a:14:{s:2:"id";a:6:{s:4:"type";s:7:"integer";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";i:11;s:8:"unsigned";b:0;s:3:"key";s:7:"primary";}s:8:"username";a:7:{s:4:"type";s:6:"string";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";i:255;s:3:"key";s:5:"index";s:7:"collate";s:15:"utf8_general_ci";s:7:"charset";s:4:"utf8";}s:8:"password";a:6:{s:4:"type";s:6:"string";s:4:"null";b:1;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";i:255;s:7:"collate";s:15:"utf8_general_ci";s:7:"charset";s:4:"utf8";}s:17:"num_free_listings";a:5:{s:4:"type";s:7:"integer";s:4:"null";b:1;s:7:"default";s:1:"0";s:6:"length";i:2;s:8:"unsigned";b:0;}s:3:"pin";a:6:{s:4:"type";s:6:"string";s:4:"null";b:1;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";i:255;s:7:"collate";s:15:"utf8_general_ci";s:7:"charset";s:4:"utf8";}s:7:"is_ldap";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:7:"boolean";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";i:1;}s:13:"ldap_username";a:6:{s:4:"type";s:6:"string";s:4:"null";b:1;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";i:255;s:7:"collate";s:15:"utf8_general_ci";s:7:"charset";s:4:"utf8";}s:8:"fullname";a:6:{s:4:"type";s:6:"string";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";i:255;s:7:"collate";s:15:"utf8_general_ci";s:7:"charset";s:4:"utf8";}s:8:"group_id";a:5:{s:4:"type";s:7:"integer";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";s:1:"2";s:6:"length";i:11;s:8:"unsigned";b:0;}s:16:"password_changed";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:4:"date";s:4:"null";b:1;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";N;}s:10:"last_login";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:8:"datetime";s:4:"null";b:1;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";N;}s:6:"status";a:6:{s:4:"type";s:26:"enum('active','suspended')";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";s:6:"active";s:6:"length";i:9;s:7:"collate";s:15:"utf8_general_ci";s:7:"charset";s:4:"utf8";}s:7:"created";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:8:"datetime";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";N;}s:8:"modified";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:8:"datetime";s:4:"null";b:0;s:7:"default";N;s:6:"length";N;}}
```

Can I convert this (serialized php?) to SQL and recreate my table, if so how? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP create a file:

```
<?php
class AppSchema extends CakeSchema {

public function before($event = array()) {
    return true;
}

public function after($event = array()) {
}    

$dir = 'files/';
$files = [
    'table_names' => 'myapp_cake_model_default_mydb_tablenames',

];
foreach ($files as $table => $file){
$content = file(realpath( $dir.$file ));
$content = unserialize($content[1]);
$info = null;
foreach ($content as $field => $prop){
    $info .= "'$field' => array(";
        foreach ($prop as $key => $value){
            $info .= "'$key' => ";
            if($key == 'null'){
                $info .= empty($value)?'false':'true';
            }elseif($key == 'default'){
                $info .= empty($value)?'null':"'$value'";
            }elseif($key == 'unsigned'){
                $info .= empty($value)?'false':'true';
            }else{
                $info .= empty($value)?"''":"'$value'";
            }
            $info .= ", ";
        }
    $info .= "),\n";
}
echo "public $".$table." = array(
    ".$info."'indexes' => array(
        'PRIMARY' => array('column' => 'id', 'unique' => 1),
    ),
    'tableParameters' => array('charset' => 'utf8', 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci', 'engine' => 'InnoDB')
 );\n\n";
}
?>
}
```

Then run it in the browser and you should get some code to paste a the schema.php file.  Then use the Cake console to create the tables in the MySQL database.